# First-chance exception at 0x0FBD8B51 (msvcr120d.dll) in Higher Or Lower.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x74742E6C

Tags: c++, exception, sdl, sfml

I would like to make a program that generates a random number between 1-10, gets the player to guess if the next number will be higher or lower.
I have decided to code this in c++, SDL SFML. I have this exception that crashes my game:

```
First-chance exception at 0x0FBD8B51 (msvcr120d.dll) in Higher Or Lower.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x74742E6C.
```

The code that is causing it is:

```
if (!font.loadFromFile("arial.ttf"))
    cout << "Error: Can not load the font 'arial.ttf' from file!" << endl;
```

It runs in `Release` fine but in `Debug` it gets this runtime error

Comment: Your file `arial.ttf` is in the same location from where you are executing the program if not could your try giving the entire path. `Access violation reading location 0x74742E6C.` means location you are trying to read does not exist

Comment: @VinayShukla It is where it is supposed to be, I have tried using `if(!font.loadFromFile("Higher Or Lower\Arial"))` but it does not work http://imgur.com/yEVSb5g

Comment: The address of the access violation `0x74742E6C` happens to be be the hex representation of `'l.tt'` i.e the characters at offsets 4-7 from your font name.  This is almost certainly due to a mismatch between debug & release compiled files.  That fact it works in `release` but not `debug` suggests that you are using the `release` library with your `debug` build.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, It was a VS bug. I made a new project and it works!